# Find last occurrence of character in string Python

Tags: python

How would I find the last occurrence of a character in a string?

```
string = "abcd}def}"
string = string.find('}',last) # Want something like this
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use `rfind`:

```
>>> "abcd}def}".rfind('}')
8
```